# Latest AL2 AMI (amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20230418.0-x86_64-gp2) running very old cloud-init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, cloud-init

Attempting to bootstrap EC2 instances with specific UIDs for users as well as NFS mounts (for EFS).

Neither of these seem to be working, notably because cloud-init 19 doesn't support the directives (and in the case of the mounts, doesn't recognise network paths as mount addresses and gives up.). This functionality was added in [version 20.2](https://github.com/delphix/cloud-init/commit/1a838faf33f1a74a59e63c161bc93eabe8275e76) - 3 years ago.

Is there any sensible way to run a later version of cloud-init on an al2 instance without re-rolling an AMI? Is there any reason this is held back to a 4 year old version?